# Android: Why onTouchListener() opens more than one Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, ontouchlistener

Here's the code:

```
        textView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            String content = textView1.getText().toString();
            if (!content.equals("")){
                showNameDialog();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Pretty simple. If the string content has text inside of it, it executes the showNameDialog() method.

Here's the method:

```
    private void showNameDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(name.toString().toUpperCase());
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Name's frequency: " + arrayListToString);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    }
```

It all works pretty well, except for the fact that when I click on textView1, it opens two, three or four AlertDialogs. Why? How can I make it open just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Touches aren't clicks, so I'd assume that onTouch can be called multiple times while the View is touched (on touch down, then touch up, etc). Instead try using an OnClickListener:

```
textView1.setClickable (true);
textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String content = textView1.getText().toString();
            if (!content.equals("")){
                showNameDialog();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works, but, it works only from the second click on. That's an usual behavior?

Comment: what does secondary click mean? In the screen is only possible one click with the finger, right?

Comment: @EricsonWillians Check your xml layout file if there is such attribute android:focusableInTouchMode="true". If element is focusable in touch mode it will gain focus first and then perform click.

Answer (score 3):

Try use this code

```
textView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        String content = textView1.getText().toString();
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                if (!content.equals("")){
                            showNameDialog();
                    }
            }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! It opens just one, and it works on the first click, just how I wanted.